# Neo4j index query with regex

Tags: regex, indexing, neo4j

I am trying to get likers for some artists through an index on Name :

```
START n=node:Artist(Name =~ 'Michael*.')
MATCH n<-[:LIKES]-liker
return liker.Id, n.Label
LIMIT 50
```

And I have this error :
Invalid query
string literal or parameter expected
"START n=node:ArtistId(Name =~ 'Michael*.')"

I am wondering how can I use regex in index query?
I know I can use regex in match but I don't know how can I use regex in START.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use normal regex syntax, but you can use wildcards:

```
START n=node:Artist('Name:Michael*')
```

**Edit**:

Neo4J uses [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches) for index queries.  You have a few other cool things you can do in addition to wildcards.

Comment: Thanks, that's why I supposed.

Comment: Do you know if Neo4j team has planned to add this feature on a new release ?

Comment: I have no idea.  See my updated answer for other things to try.

Comment: Yes, that works on pre 2.0. Read the Cypher docs of the version you need it for though.