# How to optimize neo4j cypher query in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, neo4j, cypher

How can I improve the search time for this simple Neo4j regEx query?

I am using node's neo4j module. My query is very simple, it applies a regex to 30,000 beer nodes, returning any nodes that have a name property that contains the regEx string. The returned result is approx 2,000 nodes, and **it currently takes 80,000ms to complete**.

```
db.query("MATCH (n:Beer) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*"+ String+".*' RETURN n", function(data) {
  //do some stuff
  //res.send(data)
})
```

Comment: Did you ran the same query in the browser to see on which side of the app it can come ?

Comment: Have you can had a look at wildcards and the Lucene indexes: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-search.html ?

Here another question on SO about the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175546/neo4j-index-query-with-regex

Comment: Turns out I had too many tabs open in my browser...closing my extra 15 tabs brought the query time down from 80,000ms to 2,000ms. I was running the server locally on my laptop.